# I'm getting some strange ArrayList value

Tags: java, arraylist

1. Please see the below code while executing below code I'm getting some strange ArrayList

   ```
    List<WebElement> optionsFromUi = driver.findElements(By.xpath(prop.getProperty("optionvalue")));
    List<String> uiOptions = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (WebElement optionsUi : optionsFromUi) {
        System.out.println("3");
        uiOptions.add(optionsUi.getText());

    }
    System.out.println("uiOptions  from UI..........  =  " + uiOptions);
    System.out.println("Size of list = " + uiOptions.size());
    List<String> strTest = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=0;i<=uiOptions.size()-1;i++){
        String str =  uiOptions.get(i);
        strTest.add(str);
    }
    System.out.println("strTest  --------------------"+strTest);
   ```
2. I am expecting below ArrayList as Output

   ```
   strTest = [Like Equals Between, Equals Like, Like Equals In, Equals]
   ```
3. But I am getting below ArrayList as Output

   ```
    strTest = [Like
               Equals
               Between, Equals
               Like, Like
               Equals
               In, Equals]
   ```

Comment: Please format your code, it is impossible to read and format it here.

Comment: can you put what does `uiOptions` contains ?

Comment: I believe that the text on your page has the line breaks so that you get the breaks in your output.

Answer (score 1):

You must be using Selenium? Then the `optionsUi.getText()` returns exactly what the string is displayed on the page including line breaks.
To print as you are expecting, just remove the line breaks when adding text to the list.

```
String str =  uiOptions.get(i).replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "");
```